# 35 GB/day of "PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer..." in syslog

Tags: syslog, pcie

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Dell XPS 8940
- latest BIOS 2.4.0

New install, and system seems to be working fine, but I have 35 gigs/day of syslog error messages like:

```
Feb 25 00:00:10 mumsilar kernel: [32409.088886] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0
Feb 25 00:00:10 mumsilar kernel: [32409.088907] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Feb 25 00:00:10 mumsilar kernel: [32409.088908] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:   device [8086:4c01] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
Feb 25 00:00:10 mumsilar kernel: [32409.088910] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:    [ 6] BadTLP
Feb 25 00:00:19 mumsilar kernel: [32418.024062] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0
Feb 25 00:00:19 mumsilar kernel: [32418.024100] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Feb 25 00:00:19 mumsilar kernel: [32418.024102] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:   device [8086:4c01] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Feb 25 00:00:19 mumsilar kernel: [32418.024103] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:    [ 0] RxErr
Feb 25 00:00:20 mumsilar kernel: [32418.431966] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0
Feb 25 00:00:20 mumsilar kernel: [32418.432012] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Feb 25 00:00:20 mumsilar kernel: [32418.432014] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:   device [8086:4c01] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Feb 25 00:00:20 mumsilar kernel: [32418.432016] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:    [ 0] RxErr
Feb 25 00:00:20 mumsilar kernel: [32418.443484] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0
Feb 25 00:00:20 mumsilar kernel: [32418.443492] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Feb 25 00:00:20 mumsilar kernel: [32418.443494] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:   device [8086:4c01] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
Feb 25 00:00:20 mumsilar kernel: [32418.443495] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:    [ 6] BadTLP
...
```

Here is the output of the following commands

```
sudo lspci -nn
sudo lspci -tv
sudo lshw -C network
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness
inxi -Fxxxrz
sudo lspci -s 00:01.0 -vvv
```

https://pastebin.com/XnvMbxm5
(added `lspci -s 00:01.0 -vvv` output)

Thanks for any help you can give.
Cheers.

P.S.

I had added this one line to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
# apparently after power saving shuts down the audio, the next time it turns on
# it will audibly pop.  Turn off shutting down the audio to prevent the popping.
# see https://superuser.com/questions/1493096/linux-ubuntu-speakers-popping-every-few-seconds#:~:text=The%20operation%20system's%20default%20behavior,value%20from%201%20to%200.
options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N
```

Comment: It's your Nvidia. Try re-seating the NVIDIA TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti]. Try using Nvidia driver 510.54. Otherwise you may have to use pci=noaer. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema thanks so much!  How did you deduce that? "00:01.0" is the PCI bridge is all I got.

Comment: If you look at `sudo lspci -tv` it'll show you what's connected to that PCI bridge... and I just noticed... you have TWO Nvidia cards. So, re-seat them both, and monitor syslog.

Comment: If re-seating, or updating the Nvidia driver helps, please let me know, and I'll write a formal answer (which you can accept for me).

Comment: @heynnema There is only one physical card.  I just reseated it, but the errors continue.  I will install 510.54 now.  I guess I'll get that from here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/186996/en-us

Comment: Let me know if 510.54 fixes it. If not, I'll give you the pci-noaer patch. Funny enough, the `sudo lspci -tv` makes it look like you have two cards. Maybe that's the problem... maybe the card has failed, and causing the error messages.

Comment: If Nvidia 510.54 doesn't solve the problem, then see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema Installed 510.54 from https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa .  Verified 510.54 is running.  Errors persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Nvidia card is causing the syslog problem.

---

```
Feb 25 00:00:10 mumsilar kernel: [32409.088886] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0
Feb 25 00:00:10 mumsilar kernel: [32409.088907] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Feb 25 00:00:10 mumsilar kernel: [32409.088908] pcieport 0000:00:01.0:   device [8086:4c01] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
```

---

```
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4c01] (rev 01)
```

---

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0-[ff]--
           +-01.0-[02]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti]
           |            +-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller
           |            +-00.2  NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller
           |            \-00.3  NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER]
```

Try Nvidia 510.54. Try a different video card, if you can get access to one.

To quiet the syslog noise, do this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

Find:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

Save the file.

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Update #1:**

Fixed by turning off ASPM: pcie_aspm=off

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-on-jetson-nano/155780

Comment: fixed by turning off ASPM: pcie_aspm=off (ref forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/…)