# "AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0" cost a long time when poweroff

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, pcie

Sorry for my English.

**Description**

- In brief, when poweroff or reboot, the "Kubuntu" logo keeps flickering for about a minute. The logo only shows for a few seconds if this error doesn't happen.
- Sometimes this error doesn't happen
- The only known way to avoid it is to click "logout" before poweroff instead of directly clicking the "poweroff" or "reboot" button
- `sudo journalctl -r`:

```
Nov 26 07:41:01 main-N960Kx systemd[1]: session-4.scope: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 26 07:41:01 main-N960Kx systemd[1]: session-4.scope: Killing process 1833 (sogoupinyi:sh6) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov 26 07:41:01 main-N960Kx systemd[1]: session-4.scope: Killing process 1830 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov 26 07:41:01 main-N960Kx systemd[1]: session-4.scope: Killing process 1811 (sogoupinyin-ser) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov 26 07:41:01 main-N960Kx systemd[1]: session-4.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.
Nov 26 07:40:33 main-N960Kx dbus-daemon[1202]: [session uid=1000 pid=1202] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Nov 26 07:40:33 main-N960Kx org.freedesktop.Notifications[4408]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Nov 26 07:40:26 main-N960Kx kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Nov 26 07:40:26 main-N960Kx kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.0:   device [8086:4c01] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Nov 26 07:40:26 main-N960Kx kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Nov 26 07:40:26 main-N960Kx kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0
Nov 26 07:40:04 main-N960Kx kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Nov 26 07:40:04 main-N960Kx kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.0:   device [8086:4c01] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Nov 26 07:40:04 main-N960Kx kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Nov 26 07:40:04 main-N960Kx kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0
Nov 26 07:39:57 main-N960Kx systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Tell Plymouth To Jump To initramfs being skipped.
Nov 26 07:39:57 main-N960Kx systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Power Off Screen.
```

**Tried methods**

I thought it is caused by my nvidia video card because my situation is quite similar to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394924/35-gb-day-of-pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-type-data-link-layer-in-sy), so I've tried the following methods:

- Install the latest nvidia driver
- `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/remove`(`lspci` output: 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e (rev a1)
  )
- `sudo nvidia-smi drain -p 0000:01:00.0 -m 1`
- Upgrade the kernel from 5.15.0 to 6.2.0

**System summary**

- `uname -a`: `Linux main-N960Kx 6.2.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct  6 10:23:26 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- OS: Kubuntu 22.04
- `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4c53 (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4c01 (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730] (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 4c11 (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Shared SRAM (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 43e9 (rev 11)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 43ea (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Management Engine Interface (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 43d2 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev 11)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43be (rev 11)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4386 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SPI Controller (rev 11)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN570 NVMe SSD
```

- `lspci -tv`:

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Device 4c53
           +-01.0-[01]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]
           |            \-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730]
           +-08.0  Intel Corporation Device 4c11
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Shared SRAM
           +-14.3  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0
           +-15.1  Intel Corporation Device 43e9
           +-15.2  Intel Corporation Device 43ea
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Management Engine Interface
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Device 43d2
           +-1c.0-[02]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-1c.6-[03]----00.0  O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
           +-1d.0-[04]----00.0  Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN570 NVMe SSD
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Device 4386
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller
           +-1f.4  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SMBus Controller
           \-1f.5  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SPI Controller
```